# Class vs Object Literal - fields immutability

Tags: typescript, cypress

Can I/is it possible to make object literal properties immutable/readonly?

```
export const Page = {
  
    email: 'input[type=email]',
    password: 'input[type=password]',

    fillLoginCredentials() {
        cy.get(this.email).type('email');
        cy.get(this.password).type('password');
    }
```

FYI: It's a page object for cypress and I know how to make them immutable using class, but I prefer object literals with simple static methods.

Overall, is there any specific reason why I should use class instead?

Comment: You can use a `const` assertion [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mLJ0aw) and that tells the compiler to treat them as `readonly` and of literal types.  It doesn't seal the object at runtime but maybe you don't care?  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to protect the object literal at runtime

Here's a simple test to prove it works.

```js
const Page = {
  email: 'input[type=email]',
  password: 'input[type=password]',
  fillLoginCredentials() {
      cy.get(this.email).type('email');
      cy.get(this.password).type('password');
  }
}

Object.freeze(Page)

it('Page properties cannot be changed', (done) => {
  try {

    Page.email = ''

  } catch (error) {

    expect(error.message).to.contain("Cannot assign to read only property 'email'")

    done()          // to ensure this branch of try/catch is entered
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From a TypeScript perspective, it's sufficent to add a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
export const Page = {
    email: 'input[type=email]',
    password: 'input[type=password]',

    fillLoginCredentials() {
        console.log('Some function');
    }
} as const;

Page.email = ''; // Error
Page.password = ''; // Error
Page.fillLoginCredentials = () => {}; // Error
```

---

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wAoEMDmw4C8cA3gFBwVzAC2WAlgDYBccA5HcmAK4wDaMATzDACNegwC6rADTlKYLKlQB3aABMW7Tj35CRCpaqhqpsuRQBmjBgBkIODgGEowNcGQw6WBqgAUAShJzSgokNAgGYAA6BntfVgBlCGp8Cy5kBE8UVn8AbmCAX1ICuEVEFHR80mw8KLFGQjZWfJrogxV1RtZm6txoqwZbeycXNw8vH0aAwgA+EgLcoA)</sup>

This won't prevent runtime changes though.